# Where are SharePoint WebPartPages located?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm very new to SharePoint and I am having trouble working out where the various templates and web part pages can be located in SharePoint Designer.

I've found the home page and the master page of the site I'm working on and there are a couple of references to other blocks of code that I can't trace.

For example:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:cms,WebPartZoneTitle_TopRightColumn%>" ID="TopRightColumn"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Where would I find the file this code references?

There is also code like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="companyName" TagName="CompanyNameFooter" Src="~/_controltemplates/CompanyNameFooter.ascx" %>
```

This apparently references a file in the directory: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES

How do I access this file from within SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access from SharePoint Application, Goto Site contents >> Pages u can see the pages which are available